# Filter by IP range in wireshark

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, wireshark

I want to get some packets depending on source IPs in Wireshark. I used this filtering:

ip.src >= 0.0.0.0 && ip.src <= 127.255.255.255

It brings me all the related packets, IN ADDITION TO some packets whose source IP is not suitable (Ex: 192.52.44.12). Whatever the filter is, even ip.src >= 0.0.0.0 && ip.src <= 1.1.1.1, I always see more packets than I am looking for and the example always included.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What packets *are* suitable?  And what do you mean by ">=" and "<=" when you're comparing IP addresses rather than numbers?

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are not integers. You can not compare them with <> operators. If you like to exclude addresses, use `ip.src != 1.2.3.4` or with cidr notation `ip.src != 1.2.3.4/24`. If you want to exclude multiple addresses, chain these filters with `&&` operator.

Comment: In reality, IP addresses _are_ unsigned integers (32 bits for IPv4 and 128 bits for IPv6), which is how network devices see and use IP addresses. The text representation of IP addresses that Wireshark uses are _not_ integers, and that is where the problem lies. Never try to manipulate the test representation of IP addresses. Instead, convert the text representation to the integer value, then do the manipulation and convert back to text for human readability.